# Why does git rebase delete a file added in the most recent commit if it was deleted by the rebase branch?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I'm trying to figure out why git rebase causes a newly created file to be deleted if the branch I'm rebasing off of deleted it. For example:

```
A1 - A2 - A3
 \
  B1

A2 = add a new file test.txt
A3 = delete test.txt
B1 = add the exact same file as A2
```

If B1 is checked out and I execute `git rebase A3`, test.txt is still deleted. I'd expect the result to be:

```
A1 - A2 - A3 - B1
```

Which would mean that test.txt still exists. Why is test.txt deleted after the rebase?

Comment: It should not be, if I am reading your question correctly. Do you have a script to reproduce this? (Write something that makes an empty directory, runs `git init`, creates files and commits, makes a branch, creates more files, etc., and last, runs the `git rebase` to show the problem.)

Comment: Sure I'll write one real quick.

Comment: Okay you can copy and paste this script http://pastebin.com/mPcmGCT5 edit: updated the script to make a directory (creates testing_git)

Comment: @maxbart this is a long shot but can you put the script from pastebin into your question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wow, this was a tough one! :-)

Using your script, I reproduced the problem.  There was something very odd about it all though, so first, I trimmed out the rebase step, leaving this (slightly modified) script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
if [ -d testing_git ]; then
    echo test dir testing_git already exists - halting
    exit 1
fi

mkdir testing_git
cd testing_git

git init
touch main.txt
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"

# setup B branch
git checkout -b B
echo hello > test.txt
git add .
git commit -m "added test.txt"

# setup master
git checkout master
echo hello > test.txt
git add .
git commit -m "added test.txt"
rm test.txt
git add .
git commit -m "remove test.txt"
```

Once run, inspecting the commits, I get this:

```
$ git log --graph --decorate | sed 's/@/ /'
* commit 249e4893ea7458f45fe5cdc496ddc0292a3f03ef (HEAD -> master)
| Author: Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com>
| Date:   Thu May 5 20:28:02 2016 -0700
| 
|     remove test.txt
|  
* commit a132dc9e3939b5338f7c784c58da9c83f4902c8d (B)
| Author: Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com>
| Date:   Thu May 5 20:28:02 2016 -0700
| 
|     added test.txt
|  
* commit 81c4d9be82094fdb4c88ed0a53bdbd5c3dfd7a5a
  Author: Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com>
  Date:   Thu May 5 20:28:02 2016 -0700

      initial commit
```

Note that `master`'s parent commit is branch `B`'s commit, and there are just three commits, not four.  How can this be, when the script runs four `git commit` commands?

Now let's add `sleep 2` to the script, right after `git checkout master`, and re-run it and see what happens...

```
[edit]
$ sh testrebase.sh
[snip output]
$ cd testing_git && git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
* cddbff1 (HEAD -> master) remove test.txt
* c4ac1b2 added test.txt
| * fefc150 (B) added test.txt
|/  
* 8c07bb6 initial commit
```

Whoa, now we have four commits, and a proper branch!

Why did the first script make three commits, and adding `sleep 2` change it to make four commits?

The answer lies in the identity of a commit.  Each commit has a (supposedly!) unique ID, which is a checksum of the contents of the commit.  Here's what was in the `B`-branch commit, the first time around:

```
$ git cat-file -p B | sed 's/@/ /'
tree c3cd0188a6a1490204e25547986e49b0b445dec8
parent 81c4d9be82094fdb4c88ed0a53bdbd5c3dfd7a5a
author Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com> 1462505282 -0700
committer Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com> 1462505282 -0700

added test.txt
```

We have the `tree`, the `parent`, two (name, email, timestamp) triples for author and committer, a blank line, and the log message.  The parent is the first commit on the master branch and the tree is the tree we made when we added `test.txt` (with its contents).

Then, when we went to make the *second* commit on the `master` branch, git made a new tree from the new files.  This tree was bit-for-bit identical to the one we just committed on branch `B`, so it got the same unique ID (remember, there's only one copy of that tree in the repo, so this is correct behavior).  Then it made a new commit *object* with my name and email and timestamps as usual, and the log message.  But this commit was bit-for-bit identical to the commit we just made on branch `B`, so we got the same ID as before, and made branch `master` point to that commit.

In other words, we *re-used the commit*.  We just made it on a different branch (so that `master` pointed to the same commit as `B`).

Adding `sleep 2` changed the *time stamp* on the new commit.  Now the two commits (in `B` and `master`) are no longer bit-for-bit identical:

```
$ git cat-file -p B | sed 's/@/ /' > bx
$ git cat-file -p master^ | sed 's/@/ /' > mx
$ diff bx mx
3,4c3,4
< author Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com> 1462505765 -0700
< committer Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com> 1462505765 -0700
---
> author Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com> 1462505767 -0700
> committer Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com> 1462505767 -0700
```

Different time stamps = different commits = much more sensible setup.

Actually executing the rebase, though, dropped the file anyway!

It turns out that this is by design.  When you run `git rebase`, the setup code does not simply list every commit for cherry-picking, but instead uses `git rev-list --right-only` to find commits that it should drop.<sup>1</sup>

Since the commit that adds `test.txt` is in the upstream, Git just drops it entirely: the assumption here is that you sent it upstream to someone, they already took it, and there is no need to take it again.

Let's modify the reproducer script *again*—and we will be able to take out the `sleep 2` this time, speeding things up—so that the change to `master` is different, and will not be removed from the list via `--cherry-pick --right-only`.  We will still add `test.txt` with the same single line, but we will also modify `main.txt` in that commit:

```
# setup master
git checkout master
echo hello > test.txt
echo and also slight difference >> main.txt
git add .
git commit -m "added test.txt"
```

We can go ahead and turn on the final `git checkout B` and `git rebase master` lines as well, and this time, rebasing works as we originally expected:

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
* c31b13a (HEAD -> B) added test.txt
* da2ca52 (master) remove test.txt
* 6972019 added test.txt
* 0f0d2e8 initial commit
$ ls
main.txt   test.txt
```

I had not realized that rebase did this; it is not something I expected (even though as the other answer points out, it *is* documented), and it means that saying "rebase is just repeated cherry-pick" is not quite correct: it's repeated cherry-pick, with special cases of dropping commits.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, for non-interactive rebase, it uses this remarkable bit:

```
git format-patch -k --stdout --full-index --cherry-pick --right-only \
--src-prefix=a/ --dst-prefix=b/ --no-renames --no-cover-letter \
"$revisions" ${restrict_revision+^$restrict_revision} \
>"$GIT_DIR/rebased-patches"
```

where `$revisions` expands, in this case, to `master...B`.

The `--cherry-pick --right-only` options to `git format-patch` are not documented; one must know to look in the `git rev-list` documentation for them.

Interactive rebase uses a different technique but still selects away any commits that are already in the upstream.  This shows up if you change `rebase` to `rebase -i` in that the rebase instructions consist of one `noop` line instead of the expected single `pick` line.

Answer (score 3):

As [`git rebase` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) says:

> Note that any commits in HEAD which introduce the same textual changes as a commit in HEAD..<upstream> are omitted (i.e., a patch already accepted upstream with a different commit message or timestamp will be skipped).

In your case `B1` introduce the same change as `A2`. So that, when you do rebase, `B1` is omitted from rebase process, as <upstream> already have that patch. You can add `-i` option to do interactive rebase. That allows you to see, that `B1` is not listed in todo list of rebase process. Although, you can pick that commit manually by adding `pick B1` in todo list of interactive rebase.

Comment: squashing my branch with `rebase -i` and then rebasing onto the other branch worked