# Git rebase onto branch but treat all differences as commits

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-branch-sculpting

I have a bunch of bash scripts loaded from my .bashrc that I store in a private github repo so I can use them across computers.  Each computer has its own quirks, so I have a branch for each one.  I started this project on my work computer, so `master` has a bunch of code that's not relevant for my home environments.

In those branches, I've deleted the work-related changes, however it would be much better if I could make `work` its own branch and make `master` a base, non-customized set of code.  That way, whenever I make a change in my `work` branch, I don't get merge conflicts about deleted files when I rebase my home computers onto `master`.  However, I want to make changes to `master` that apply to all of my branches; if I then rebase `work` back onto `master`--which has deleted my work code--`work` will receive those deletions.

How can I branch `master` into `work`, delete the work-related changes on `master`, and then rebase `work` back onto my cleaned `master` without deleting all the work-related code in `work`?

I could use `git rebase --interactive` and split out all of my work changes since the beginning of time, but that seems tedious for an action that can't be all that uncommon.

I saw `git rebase --onto` and `git filter-branch` but from what I read, neither of those look like the right approach.

Comment: What do you mean by "all differences"?

Comment: I mean don't change any of the code of the rebasing branch that was deleted by the base branch.

Comment: `Each computer has its own quirks, so I have a branch for each one` sounds like a nightmare. Consider researching a templating system, like `chezmoi`. ` I branch master into work` - `git checkout master ; git checkout -b work` - `delete the work-related changes on master` - `git reset --hard <commitid>` - `then rebase work back onto my cleaned master` - I do not understand that part. If `work` is on top of `master` there's nothing to rebase. If you want to shuffle commits, yes, use `git rebase -i`.

Comment: If the commit being rebased adds or changes the code then it must change it... why rebase at all? The "base-branch" won't be affected however.

Comment: @KamilCuk When I make changes in `master` that apply to all branches, I need to rebase each branch onto master, no?  If master has deleted files that are in `work`, and I rebase to get my new changes, then all my deletions will also apply.

Comment: @dx_over_dt are you treating branches as separate projects?

Comment: @evolutionxbox No?  Depends on what you mean by projects.  I define a bunch of aliases/functions/variables in `~/shellrc/*` which are loaded by `.bashrc`.  *Most* of those are common to all of my computers.  However, each computer has its own set of custom values.

Comment: @KamilCuk I peeked at chezmoi.  It looks exactly like what I'm trying to achieve with my repo.  I'll look into setting it up.  Thanks!

Comment: `onto master, no?` yes. `then all my deletions will also apply` Yes, but if there are new commits on those deleted files, you'll get rebase conflicts that you have to manually deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I branch master into work, delete the work-related changes on master, and then rebase work back onto my cleaned master without deleting all the work-related code in work?

A rebase onto master would use a... `rebase --onto`:

```
git rebase --onto master $(git merge-base master work) work
```

That would replay your commits from work on top of the cleaned master

```
  git merge-base master work
      |
m--m--m--M       (master, cleaned-up)
       \
        w--w--w  (work)

    git rebase --onto master $(git merge-base master work) work

m--m--m--M            (master, cleaned-up)
          \
           w'--w'--w' (work, rebased)
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work.  `work` received all the deletions I made in `master`.

Comment: @dx_over_dt Strange, considering work is supposed to be replayed on top of master, recreating those deleted files.

Comment: I think the issue may be that work is essentially master renamed.  When it does the rebase --onto, there is no w to become w'.  w is just the m before M.

Comment: @dx_over_dt Got it: I now know whay rebase drop those files (deleted in master): https://stackoverflow.com/a/37064182/6309. Are those files modified in work?

Comment: They haven't been yet

Comment: @dx_over_dt Can you try and modify them (in the work branch) *before* the rebase? Even a dummy modification.

Comment: Sorry for the wait.  I added a space to the file and committed.  `rebase --onto master` worked great, after that!